# Show content of Lotus Notes mail in browser using IMAP

Tags: java, email, imap, lotus-notes

I have to implement the following in Java. I have a search result which is a list of emails (breve description) as link. I want that, when the user clicks on the link, the web application opens a popup to show the content of the email. But the email is a Lotus Notes email and I have to user IMAP to open the mail.

If this can be done also in an other language or from the commadline, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have local access to the nsf file which holds the email, you can simply use the standard Java classes to open database and inspect documents as usual, but for that to happen, your Java client must run in the same workstation where the user is checking his local email, and he has to have Lotus Notes client installed.

If that's not the case... Then it's going to be more difficult, and there are a few approaches, but you would probably need to give some more background... Could you maybe clarify this?

### EDIT 1

I do understand that you are looking to use IMAP, I am just wondering if maybe you have local access to the mail database as a shortcut...

### EDIT 2

I've just spoken with an old colleague, he mentioned to me that you shouldn't find any issue accessing the email through IMAP if properly configured, is there any particular problem that you are seeing?

Also, you may want to consider the standard remote access API to access Lotus Domino for Java, [here you have some introductory information](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/).

### EDIT 3 (as per OP comment)

If you have local access to the user's Lotus Notes client, as it seems by your comment, then you may only need to format your URLs following this convention `notes://server/database/document`, this should open automatically any document, including the email in your user's client. Find more information at [Notes URLs](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls).

Comment: this is the real problem:I have a list of email(breve description of the email) found by an enterprise search engine as hyperlink. I want when the user clicks on the link, lotus notes should be launch(open) the the user can see the content of the email.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that Domino provides a Webmail Interface called iNotes that even offers a RSS feed for the Inbox?

Otherwise, using IMAP4 with the users credentials, delivers everything back you need to render the short list as well as the whole mail.
Be aware of the performance impact IMAP4 causes on the server.