# How to dynamically open a Lotus Notes email in Java

Tags: email, lotus-notes, launch

How can I dynamically open a lotus notes email in Java or any other programming language?

Comment: Do you mean open the mail client, or access the contents of an email programmatically?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209244/show-content-of-lotus-notes-mail-in-browser-using-imap.

Comment: I have a list of email(breve description of the email) found by an enterprise search engine as hyperlink. I want when the user clicks on the link, lotus notes should be launch(open) the the user can see the content of the email.

Answer (score 0):

If notes is installed correctly, there should be a protocol handler for notes url's like
notes://[SERVER]/[Replikaid]/[View]/[DocumentID]

If you only have the messageid, you could add a new view (byMessageID) into the mailbox with the first sorted column to the messageid field. The url would look like
notes://server/replikaid/byMessageID/messageid?Opendocument

Comment: How can I get the documentId in java. What i hava as id for the email is something like this Message-ID: <CAO6mZPgGY2sY4ErqDsL+K2WyPBBKDCn92LS0xBVPgkkBd5S_ZA@mail.gmail.com>

Comment: Search for it. Notesdatabase.search("$messageid=" & [imapid],nothing,0)